# Minesweeper odds for this scenario, 2 different calculations

Tags: probability, combinations

I am trying to calculate the odds, for every square (Except M or Q) of a mine being there, without knowing the total mines on the board.

I've found 2 different formulas online, which are similar except for one portion & although produce the same number for some sections, a very different answer is given for sections of the board. For example, the blue section I have 2 different answers for.

[image]

As you can see I've split up the squares into logical sections, where the probability will be the same.

For better explanation, the board looks like this:

```
ABCDE
F3G1H
IJ1KL
MNOPQ
```

The sections, broken up by the number they 'touch':

```
Section           # of bombs in section:
-------           ----------------------
(A+B+C+F+G+I+J) = 3
(C+D+E+G+H+K+L) = 1
(G+J+K+N+O+P)   = 1
```

*Note: that I am using the # of bombs to mean the number of bombs contained inside the squares. For example, The green section (A+B+F+I) are 4 squares. At most 4 squares can have 4 mines (1 mine per square). In our case green cannot contain 4 mines though, because of the '3'.*

Further broken up, Here we get the sections you see in the image. By breaking up sections when we know which squares will give the same odds. I will call these the 'known solutions', or 'absolute solutions' (The right column is the # of bombs inside all of the squares combined):

```
(A+B+F+I) + (C) + (G) + (J) = 3
(G) + (C) + (D+E+H+L) + (K) = 1
(J) + (N+O+P) + (K) + (G) = 1
```

Here we calculate all of the possible solutions.

We do this by making assumptions. First we assume (C) has 1 bomb. In other words, the 'C' square is a bomb. (C is chosen at random, but I prefer to start with a small section). I'll call the first solution 'A1-1':

```
(C) = 1
```

Since (C) = 1, and ((G) + (C) + (D+E+H+L) + (K)) = 1, we know that (G), (K) and (DEHL) are must be 0:

```
(G) = 0
(D+E+H+L) = 0
(K) = 0
```

But now we need to make another assumption. I chose (J) = 1. Again, I prefer starting with small sections. This gives us an entire solution (A1-1):

```
Grouping   # of bombs
--------   -----------
(C)       = 1
(D+E+H+L) = 0
(K)       = 0
(G)       = 0
(J)       = 1
(N+O+P)   = 0
(A+F+I+B) = 1
```

I'll keep assuming (C) is 1 until we've come up with every solution (Note the 'absolute solutions' must always hold true, since that's how Minesweeper works, and we want to utilize what we know:

```
(a1-2)      # of bombs
----        ----------
(C)       = 1
(D+E+H+L) = 0
(K)       = 0
(G)       = 0
(J)       = 0
(N+O+P)   = 1
(A+F+I+B) = 2
```

That's all for C = 1, so next we assume G=1:

```
a2-1        # of bombs
----        ----------
(C)       = 0
(G)       = 1
(D+E+H+L) = 0
(K)       = 0
(N+O+P)   = 0
(J)       = 0
(A+F+I+B) = 2

a2-2
----
(C)       = 0
(G)       = 0
(J)       = 1
(A+F+I+B) = 2
(N+O+P)   = 0
(D+E+H+L) = 1
(K)       = 0

a2-3
----
(C)       = 0
(G)       = 0
(J)       = 0
(K)       = 1
(D+E+H+L) = 0
(A+F+I+B) = 3
(N+O+P)   = 0

a2-4
----
(C)       = 0
(G)       = 0
(J)       = 0
(K)       = 0
(D+E+H+L) = 1
(A+F+I+B) = 3
(N+O+P)   = 1
```

That gives us every solution.

Now we list the **number of bombs in every possible solution**:

Note that: 
(A+F+I+B) is Green, 
(C)       is Pink, 
(D+E+H+L) is orange, 
(G)       is brown, 
(J)       is Yellow, 
(K)       is Purple
(N+O+P)   is blue:

```
#:      A1  A12 A21 A22 A23 A24
GREEN:  1   2   2   2   3   3
PINK:   1   1   0   0   0   0   
ORANGE: 0   0   0   1   0   1
BROWN:  0   0   1   0   0   0
YELLOW: 1   0   0   1   0   0
PURPLE: 0   0   0   0   1   0
BLUE:   0   1   0   0   0   1
```

Now we calculate the combinations possible for every solution. This is done by using nCr ([Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)).

**Where N = Number of Squares and B = numberOfBombs.**

**Combinations = N NCR B.**

For the first solution (A1-1) these are the combinations:

```
(GREEN)   = 4 NCR 1 = 4
(PINK)    = 1 NCR 1 = 1
(ORANGE)  = 4 NCR 0 = 1
(BROWN)   = 1 NCR 0 = 1
(YELLOW)  = 1 NCR 1 = 1
(PURPLE)  = 0 NCR 1 = 1
(BLUE)    = 3 NCR 0 = 1
```

Multiplying these combinations we get: 4*1*1*1*1*1*1 = **4 combinations for this solution (A1-1).**

Doing the same for all solutions we get:

```
#:      A1  A12 A21 A22 A23 A24
GREEN:  4   6   6   6   4   4
PINK:   1   1   1   1   1   1   
ORANGE: 1   1   1   4   1   4
BROWN:  1   1   1   1   1   1
YELLOW: 1   1   1   1   1   1
PURPLE: 1   1   1   1   1   1
BLUE:   1   3   1   1   1   3
TOTALS: 4   18  6   24  4   48

Total combinations = 104
```

Note: In the above table, to get 'TOTALS' we *multiply* all combinations to get the total combinations for that solution.

Now for the part that I am conflicted on. I choose 'Blue' to demonstrate, since I am getting a different answer using either method.

**Method 1:**

For each solution take the number of mines divided by the number of squares (3) and multiply by the combinations:

```
A1-1      A1-2      A2-1    A2-2     A2-3    A2-4
(0/3*4)   (1/3*18)  (0/3*6) (0/3*24) (0/3*4) (1/3*48)
```

Adding those numbers up (Taking away the 0's to make it easier):

```
(1/3*18) + (1/3*48) = 22.
```

Now divide by the total combinations (104):

```
22/104 = 0.212.
```

However there are 3 squares, so we can divide by 3 if we want the odds of a single square in the section:

```
0.212/3 = 0.0705
```

**Method 2**

Multiply the total combinations for the non-zero values (48 + 18), divide by the total combinations (104):

```
1*66/104 = .635.
```

Again we can divide by 3 if we want the odds of a single square:

```
.635/3 = .212
```

So, are my odds for hitting a mine on any given blue square `.212%`, `.0705%`, or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I upvoted because you have presented an intriguing problem coupled with what appears to be a reasonable try at a solution.  I did not understand your work, however.  Even if I had, this is not the approach that I would take.

I would write a computer program to :

1. Identify and count all possible mine configurations that satisfy the original conditions.  Denote this count as $d$.
2. Identify and count all possible mine configurations that satisfy the original conditions, and also satisfy that one of the blue squares contains a mine.  Denote this count as $n$.

Then the desired probability is $n/d.$

I regard the above as the **industrial strength** approach.  I also suspect that any alternative approach that attempts to use *mathematical analysis* will be **very problematic.**

**Addendum-1**

I scrutinized the OP's query until **"Now for the part that I am conflicted on..."**, and I didn't bother trying
to decipher the subsequent portion of his posting.  In my opinion, his logic is flawless to that point and in fact
he has solved the problem.

Assuming that I am not mistaken, the answer is $x/y$, where

$x = 18+48$ and

$y = 4+18+6+24+4+48$.

**Addendum-2**

See also [Minesweeper revisited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459321/minesweeper-revisited/3459640#3459640)
which confronts the issue that the cases examined in this *answer* (e.g. the 104 cases referred to in addendum-1) are **not equally likely**.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more of an explanation, I am splitting the squares into groups, where they contain the same odds.

Comment: @dustytrash I understood your edited query up to "...Here we calculate all of the possible...".  In order to get me or someone else to take a thorough look at your analysis you're going to have to further edit your query **so that it is impossible for the reader to be confused.**

Comment: Updated my answer. Reading it this morning I see how it was confusing / lacking explanation

Comment: @dustytrash  Your revision looks much better, but still needs some editing, unless I have misinterpreted your work.  Specifically, at the point where you write **"We do this by Making an assumptions. First we assume (C) = 1"**, it appears that you are using the equation **"(C) = 1"** *ambiguously* to represent that square C has a mine *&/or* that of all the squares touching square C, exactly one of them has a mine.  If I have interpreted your query correctly, you need to edit the query to **remove the ambiguity.**

Comment: I've updated my answer, I meant that C=1 means C Is a mine, since C is 1 square in length.

Comment: @dustytrash : I now have two responses. (First response) Minor typo that needs editing : **"Since (C) = 1, ... we know that (G), (C), (DEHL) are must be 0 (AKA ...):"** I surmise that you intended that (G), (DEHL) all must be 0 since (C) = 1. (2nd response) see my *answer's* **addendum-1**.

Comment: @dustytrash  see my *answer's* addendum.

Comment: @dustytrash see also my answer's addendum-2.

Comment: Am I able to add the formula in addendum-2, to my '104 cases' to correct my formula (If the number of mines, and other unidentified squares is known)? Am I understanding correctly that the 104 are *not* all equal?

Comment: @dustytrash **Yes**, you've got it.  A reasonable approach is to *contrast* my follow-up query with the **answer** that it received, and then decide on an **estimate** for judging **how much more likely one case is than another.**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I believe I understand. I'll be posting another question in a few days with this information

Comment: I've mentioned this answer in a new post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463628/calculating-odds-of-minesweeper-is-this-correct

Comment: Stumbled upon this post. Great answer (+1)!