# Calculating odds of Minesweeper is this correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

### EDIT

Please see new question: [Calculating Minesweeper Odds Is this calculation correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466402/calculating-minesweeper-odds-is-this-calculation-correct)

The answers here helped me create the new question (The post below has some errors which makes it harder to review)

### The below question is only kept for historical purposes.

---

So I originally asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447402/minesweeper-odds-for-this-scenario-2-different-calculations), given that the number of mines was unknown.

However user2661923 pointed out that **the 104 different possibilities do not have an equal weight**.

For example, having 4 mines in total is more likely than having 5 mines in total. We know this without knowing the total mines because in Minesweeper there are always a greater number of unmined cells than mined cells.

See [this question & answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459321/minesweeper-revisited/3459640#3459640) for a detailed explanation as to why the 104 combinations are not all equal weight

### Problem

I want to calculate the odds of hitting a mine in any of the spaces. I will apply my original calculation & the new information to this board where the number of mines is known (**25**):

[image]

**N = number of mines = 25.**

**T = number of unidentified squares = 124**

**ABFI,B,C..NOP,RSTUVWXY** (All labeled squares minus M & Q) I'll refer to as **Section1**

The **grey squares** (including M & Q) I'll refer to as **Section2**

I've broken up the board into colour groups based on the probabilities. Every square in the green group will have the same probability. Every square in the grey group will have the same probability and so on.

We know this based on the numbered squares the square is touching. For example, 'A' & 'B' both touch a '3'. There is no reason 'B' would have different odds than 'A'.

I've labeled the board for my own sake, to be able to refer to the squares of interest (*M & Q are not interesting, they are part of section2 I just wanted a square of marked squares*)

Based on this we know:

**Section1 can have 4, or 5 or 6 mines.**

**Section2 can have 21, 20, or 19 mines.** (Remember section2 is 'the rest' aka gray squares)

I'll refer to what we know as 'Rules'. We know the total number of mines surrounding a '1' must equal '1'.

**Rules:**

```
ColorGroups                          # of bombs in ColorGroups
-----------                          ----------------------------
(A+B+F+I) + (C) + (G) + (J) =        3
(D+E+H+L) (C) + (G) + (K)   =        1
(N+O+P) + (J) + (K) + (G)   =        1
(R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y)           =        1
```

Before collecting every possible combination, Let's look at the formula for assigning weights (Found in the 'question & answer' linked at the top, Credit to user Joriki in the linked answer):

[image]

```
m = remaining mines (25)
t = remaining unidentified squares (124)
n = mines assigned
s = assigned squares
```

Let's assume Section1 has 4 mines (Section2 must have the remaining 21):

```
m = 25
t = 124
n = 4
s = 23 (Remember M & Q are not part of this section).

124 - 23 = 101
25 - 4 = 21
101 ncr 21 = 2577824781465941808570
```

Assuming Section1 has 5 mines:

```
m = 25
t = 124
n = 5
s = 23

124 - 23 = 101
25 - 5 = 20
101 ncr 20 = 668324943343021950370
```

Finally, assuming Section1 has 6 mines:

```
m = 25
t = 124
n = 6
s = 23

124 - 23 = 101
25 - 6 = 19
101 ncr 19 = 163006083742200475700
```

Calculating all of the possibilities *(I refer to these as 'Scenarios')* the same way we've done in the original post tells us there are 6 different possibilities for Section1:

```
#:      A1  A12 A21 A22 A23 A24
GREEN:  1   2   2   2   3   3
PINK:   1   1   0   0   0   0   
ORANGE: 0   0   0   1   0   1
BROWN:  0   0   1   0   0   0
YELLOW: 1   0   0   1   0   0
PURPLE: 0   0   0   0   1   0
BLUE:   0   1   0   0   0   1
RED:    1   1   1   1   1   1
Total:  4   5   4   5   5   6
```

*Note: I described & listed all scenerios in the original post.*

As done in the original post, taking the NCR for all combinations (Adding Red here, gives us the same result since Red is always 1):

```
#:      A1  A12 A21 A22 A23 A24
GREEN:  4   6   6   6   4   4
PINK:   1   1   1   1   1   1   
ORANGE: 1   1   1   4   1   4
BROWN:  1   1   1   1   1   1
YELLOW: 1   1   1   1   1   1
PURPLE: 1   1   1   1   1   1
BLUE:   1   3   1   1   1   3
RED:    1   1   1   1   1   1
TOTALS: 4   18  6   24  4   48

Total combinations = 104
```

*Note: In the above table, to get 'TOTALS' we multiply all combinations to get the total combinations for that solution.*

Tallying up the number of mines for the known sections we see there are 1 scenerios where the sections contains 6 mines, 2 scenarios which have 4 mines and 3 that have 5 mines.

To normalize the weights:

```
3 * 2577824781465941808570 = 7.7334743e+21
2 * 668324943343021950370 = 1.3366499e+21
1 * 163006083742200475700 = 163006083742200475700 

7.7334743e+21 + 1.3366499e+21 + 163006083742200475700  = 9.2331303e+21

2577824781465941808570 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.279%
668324943343021950370 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.072%
163006083742200475700 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.018%
```

So, for each 'scenario' for section1, we can assign the weights:

```
4 mine scenarios weight = 0.279%
5 mine scenarios weight = 0.072%
6 mine scenarios weight = 0.018%
```

Since 'Section1' is nearly identical to the scenario in my last question I can take the results but apply the weights:

*m (number of mines), divide by t (squares) times c (total combinations for the solution) multiplied by the weight (based on total mines for the solution. 4 is 0.279, 5 is 0.072, 6 is 0.018)*

### A11

```
Colour   m/t * c      Weight      Result
------   ----------   ------      ------
Green  = (1/4 * 4) *  0.279    =  0.279
Pink   = (1/1 * 4) *  0.279    =  1.116
Orange = (0/4 * 4) *  0.279    =  0.00
Brown  = (0/1 * 4) *  0.279    =  0.00
Yellow = (1/1 * 4) *  0.279    =  1.116
Purple = (0/1 * 4) *  0.279    =  0.00
Blue   = (0/1 * 4) *  0.279    =  0.00
Red    = (1/8 * 4) *  0.279    =  0.14
```

### A12

```
Colour   m/t * c      Weight      Result
------   ----------   ------      ------
Green  = (2/4 * 18) * 0.072    =  0.648
Pink   = (1/1 * 18) * 0.072    =  1.296
Orange = (0/4 * 18) * 0.072    =  0.00
Brown  = (0/1 * 18) * 0.072    =  0.00
Yellow = (0/1 * 18) * 0.072    =  0.00
Purple = (0/1 * 18) * 0.072    =  0.00
Blue   = (1/1 * 18) * 0.072    =  1.296
Red    = (1/8 * 18) * 0.072    =  0.162
```

### A21

```
Colour   m/t * c      Weight      Result
------   ----------   ------      ------
Green  = (2/4 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.837
Pink   = (0/1 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.00
Orange = (0/4 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.00
Brown  = (1/1 * 6)  * 0.279    =  1.674
Yellow = (0/1 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.00
Purple = (0/1 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.00
Blue   = (0/1 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.00
Red    = (1/8 * 6)  * 0.279    =  0.2093
```

### A22

```
Colour   m/t * c      Weight      Result
------   ----------   ------      ------
Green  = (2/4 * 24) * 0.279    =  3.348
Pink   = (0/1 * 24) * 0.279    =  0.00
Orange = (1/4 * 24) * 0.279    =  1.674
Brown  = (0/1 * 24) * 0.279    =  0.00
Yellow = (1/1 * 24) * 0.279    =  6.696
Purple = (0/1 * 24) * 0.279    =  0.00
Blue   = (0/1 * 24) * 0.279    =  0.00
Red    = (1/8 * 24) * 0.279    =  0.837
```

### A23

```
Colour   m/t * c      Weight      Result
------   ----------   ------      ------
Green  = (3/4 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.216
Pink   = (0/1 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.00
Orange = (0/4 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.00
Brown  = (0/1 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.00
Yellow = (0/1 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.00
Purple = (1/1 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.288
Blue   = (0/1 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.00
Red    = (1/8 * 4)  * 0.072     = 0.036
```

### A24

```
Colour   m/t * c      Weight      Result
------   ----------   ------      ------
Green  = (3/4 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.648
Pink   = (0/1 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.00
Orange = (1/4 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.216
Brown  = (0/1 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.00
Yellow = (0/1 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.00
Purple = (0/1 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.00
Blue   = (1/1 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.864
Red    = (1/8 * 48)  * 0.018    = 0.108
```

Adding up all the results, then divding by 104 (total combinations) we get the result. Then divide by the number of squares in the section to get the probability per square:

```
Green:    5.976 / 104 = 0.057 / 4 = %0.0144
Pink:     2.412 / 104 = 0.023 / 1 = %0.023
Orange:   1.89  / 104 = 0.018 / 4 = %0.0045
Brown:    1.674 / 104 = 0.016 / 1 = %0.016
Yellow:   7.812 / 104 = 0.075 / 1 = %0.075
Purple:   0.288 / 104 = 0.003 / 1 = %0.003
Blue:     2.16  / 104 = 0.208 / 3 = %0.0069
Red:      1.4923/ 104 = 0.014 / 8 = %0.0018
```

This means brown has the best odds. In a real game, the player should click one of the squares surrounding the '1'. Is this logic right?

Comment: Your 2nd link (i.e. "See this question & answer for a detailed explanation.") seems broken.  If so, please edit it.  Also, I upvoted because you *nicely* linked the other two queries to this one.

Comment: @user2661923 I fixed the link, it was broken

Comment: more editing needed, I think.  "Let's assume Section1 has 3 mines (section1 always has 1 & section2 must have the remaining 21): "  **Shouldn't this read**  "...(Section2 always has 1 & Section3 must have the remaining 21):"

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think that **you have made a critical mistake.**  You can **not assign weights to Section1 independent of Section2.**  See next comment.

Comment: If I interpreted correctly the portion of your query that immediately follows "To normalize the weights", you are **mistakenly** trying to normalize the weights in Section1 independent of Section2.  As discussed in the comments to the **2nd query** (i.e. the one that Joriki answered), you **must construe Section1 and Section2) as separate areas that form one large region.**  Consequently, **under the assumption that Section1 has 3 mines**, you **must** weight all of the *large region* by assuming **that 4 mines have been assigned to this region.**

Comment: Re previous comment, this means that the 104 cases pertinent to Section1 and the 8 cases pertinent to Section2 must be combined to represent (104 x 8) = 832 total cases.

Comment: @user2661923 If there is 4 mines in section1, there has to be 21 mines in section3 & there is always 1 mine in section1. There are only 3 possibilities for mine distributions to the 3 sections: (21, 1, 3), (20, 1, 4) (19, 1, 5)

Comment: your last comment has two mistakes: (1) there is always 1 mine in **Section2**, not Section1.  (2) Re one of my previous comments, I indicated that if Section1 has 3 mines then the **region to be analyzed** (i.e. Section1 + Section2), must have 4 mines.  Again, I repeat, see also my previous comments, re you must find all of the possible (i.e. 832) cases for the **entire region**, and assign weights accordingly.

Comment: @user2661923 I've done a big update to my answer, analyzing the 2 sections as 1. So there are now only seciton1 & section2. Tbh I don't understand how to normalize the weights against the gray section having 21, 20, 19 mines

Comment: In reading this question I realized a mistake I'd made in my answer to the other one. I've edited it accordingly. It's also relevant to this question. Sorry about that. I won't have the time today to look at this question in detail but will try to do so tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (somewhat long-winded) reaction to **part of** the OP's revised post.  My analysis only covers the query **up to AND INCLUDING** the following excerpt.  I ask the OP to consider my reaction, and consider making another edit to his post.  Then, I can (*iteratively*) examine the rest of his query.

$\underline{\text{Excerpt}}$

To normalize the weights:

```
3 * 2577824781465941808570 = 7.7334743e+21
2 * 668324943343021950370 = 1.3366499e+21
1 * 163006083742200475700 = 163006083742200475700 

7.7334743e+21 + 1.3366499e+21 + 163006083742200475700  = 9.2331303e+21

2577824781465941808570 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.279%
668324943343021950370 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.072%
163006083742200475700 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.018%
```

So, for each 'scenario' for section1, we can assign the weights:

```
4 mine scenarios weight = 0.279%
5 mine scenarios weight = 0.072%
6 mine scenarios weight = 0.018%
```

$\underline{\text{My Reactions}}$

1) As Joriki already indicated, equations like

```
2577824781465941808570 / 9.2331303e+21 = 0.279%
```

are confusing, because of the "%" sign.  I would eliminate all percent signs from your query, altering equations as needed.

2) Instead of defining $104 \times 8 = 832$ cases, you stuck with 104 cases, capitalizing on the fact that the RSTUVXYZ cells always collectively have 1 mine.  This approach is **doable** but somewhat **dangerous**, since your **intuition is evolving.**  The rest of my reaction (below) **accepts** your use of 104 cases, instead of 832 cases.

3) The math you are using is somewhat messy.  I would advise **labeling** your weights as $\binom{101}{21}, \binom{101}{20}, \;\text{and}\; \binom{101}{19}.$  **Eventually** you will convert to **relative weights**, so you will **avoid messy math.** Unfortunately, it is premature to discuss relative weights, because of the issue in my next point (below).  After you have edited your query, I will return to the issue of **relative weights.**

4) **If** I am not misinterpreting the Excerpt from your query, you are confused about how to assign the weights.  You have delineated 104 cases: one of the weights [i.e.  $\;\binom{101}{21}, \binom{101}{20}, \;\text{or}\; \binom{101}{19}]\;$
should be assigned to each of the 104 cases.  In each of the 104 cases, the weight assigned will depend on how many mines are assigned to Section1 in that case.

Assume that case 1 is assigned W1 (i.e. the weight for case 1), case 2 is assigned W2 (the weight for case 2), ..., case 104 is assigned W104.  Here, each of W1, W2, ..., W104 is one of the 3 values : $\;\binom{101}{21}, \binom{101}{20}, \;\text{or}\; \binom{101}{19}]\;$.

Let SUM_OF_WEIGHTS = W1 + W2 + ... + W104.
Let x be any integer in {1, 2, ..., 104}.

Then the probability of Case x is

{Wx : the weight assigned to case x} / {SUM_OF_WEIGHTS}.

Note that under this definition, the 
(probability of case 1) + (probability of case 2) + ... + (probability of case 104) = 1.

5) Deferred issues until your posting is edited:

5a) Converting to **relative weights** to avoid messy math.

5b) Taking the **next step** in the analysis: once you assign a probability to each of the 104 cases, you then have to decide **how to use this information to decide which minesweeper cell to click on.**  Analysis for taking the **next step** will **probably be so complex as to defy using mathematics.**  You will probably have to **merely consider what factors are relevant** and then make an **intuition-based judgement call.**

Comment: @dustytrash **Partial** reaction given to your posting - see my *answer*.

Comment: "This approach is doable but somewhat dangerous, since your intuition is evolving" My original post (before the edit) uses 104 cases. I don't believe it's complicated to consider the 8 squares will always have 1 mine (104 cases)

Comment: Still reading your post, but want to mention I'm conflicted on editing my question - yours & the other answers will become out dated. I'll have to re-read the rules on what to do here

Comment: @dustytrash "...I don't believe it's complicated...".  **Reasonable reaction.**  My *unspoken point* is that if the *righthand portion of Section1* (i.e. involving cells RSTUVXYZ) was **more complicated**, then you would need to understand how to design cases, so that each case specified a possible set of mine assignments, with the assignments **spanning all of Section1.**

Comment: @dustytrash "...I'm conflicted on editing my question...".  **Very good point.**  Assuming that you agree with the need for significant editing, I would : 1) Carefully prepare an edited query.  2) Then start a new query (new posting), which provides a link to this query (this posting) and which contains your revisions. 3) Then add a very brief **addendum** to the end of your query in *this* posting, where you explain the situation and add a link to the *next* query.

Comment: @dustytrash a moderate alternative to my last comment: because your query in this posting is **so long** many readers will **not see your addendum.**  Instead, I recommend **Starting this query**, with an explanation and the link to the *next* query, then putting in a long "-----------------------" line, and below that leaving the query **as is** perhaps with a caption like ("Original query - posting retained for historical purposes"), or some caption like that, with the caption being **in your own words.**

Comment: I've created a new question, I've marked this as the right aanswer since it contains the suggestion of making a new post

Answer (score 3):

This is slightly unnecessarily complicated.

There are two partly identified sections on the board, and in the right-hand one (with the $8$ red squares) the total of mines is known to be $1$. Thus, each red square has probability $\frac18=0.125$ of containing a mine, and we can deduct this one mine from the total of $25$ mines and calculate the left-hand section using $t=124-8=116$ and $m=25-1=24$ in my answer to the other question (with $s=15$ and $n=3,4,5$ as before). Note the correction to that answer (which you didn't have a chance to take into account yet in this calculation).

Some errors in the post:

There are some percent signs where there shouldn't be any; all the numbers seem to be probabilities out of $1$, not out of $100$.

It's not generally the case that the player should click on the square with the lowest marginal probability of containing a mine. The optimal strategy also depends on future opportunities to gain information. For instance, in the extreme case, there's no use in clicking on a square, no matter how low its marginal mine probability, if you already know that you won't gain any information by doing so.

This is also not correct:

> For example, having 4 mines in total is more likely than having 5 mines in total. We know this without knowing the total mines because in Minesweeper there are always a greater number of unmined cells than mined cells.

If you have a total of $t=100$ unidentified squares with $m=20$ mines in them, even though there are a lot more unmined cells than mined cells, if you assign mines to $s=30$ squares you'd expect about $6$ mines to be in those $30$ squares, and solutions with $5$ mines will be more probable than solutions with $4$ mines.

Comment: Although the **simplification** detailed in your answer is accurate, I still have a *moderate* criticism of it; it requires somewhat more sophisticated **intuition** to grasp its validity.  When the student's (e.g. the OP's) intuition is *still evolving*, I advocate a less elegant approach whose validity is easier to "wrap one's brain around."  Then, after the fact, the student can consider your elegant simplification and **ponder** why it leads to the same answer.

Comment: I'm creating another question with the mistakes fixed, ill be linkkng it when finished

Comment: I've created a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466402/calculating-minesweeper-odds-is-this-calculation-correct I used the suggestions from this answer, but simplified using user2661923's approach

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give a (somewhat long-winded) discussion of an excerpt from Joriki's answer.

$\underline{\text{Excerpt}}$

This is also not correct:

```
For example, having 4 mines in total is more likely than having 5 mines in total. We know this without knowing the total mines because in Minesweeper there are always a greater number of unmined cells than mined cells.
```

If you have a total of t=100
unidentified squares with m=20 mines in them, even though there are a lot more unmined cells than mined cells, if you assign mines to s=30 squares you'd expect about 6 mines to be in those 30 squares, and solutions with 5 mines will be more probable than solutions with 4 mines.

$\underline{\text{Discussion}}$

I **agree** with Joriki's analysis (excerpted above).  **However...**

I regard the *intuition* around assuming that a region is more likely to have 4 mines than 5 as **reasonable.**  The reason that it is **in error** in Joriki's example is that the region in his example is **a relatively large percentage of the number of remaining unidentified
squares.**

Joriki's rebuttal was based on $\;1/5 \times 30 = 6\;$ and 6 is closer to 5 than 4.  Based on this approach, one would **guesstimate** that if the region is 22 instead of 30, since $\;1/5 \times 22 < 4.5\;$, the chances of the region (of 22 unknown squares) having 4 mines would be slightly larger than the chances of this region having 5 mines.

Therefore, for a significantly smaller region, (e.g. a region significantly smaller than 22 unknown squares), 4 mines is more likely than 5 mines.  So the assertion (i.e. 4 mines is more likely than 5 mines), will generally hold for **smaller regions of unknown squares.**