# How to calculate if a Minesweeper alternative is beatable?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I'm a part of a game jam. I wanted to make a "harder" version of minesweeper. My idea is to build a version of minesweeper, where the value on a square is the number of mines it is touching + (the total number of mines all of it's neighbors are touching * 1/8).

Before I build it, I'm trying to figure out if this version of minesweeper is still beatable. I would consider it "beatable", if the odds of winning are similar to the original game (calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463628/calculating-odds-of-minesweeper-is-this-correct).

Comment: you can build it and play randomly and optimally for a while. You can let us know the chances.

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 neighbours and 16 second neighbours. If you have say 3 3/8 points then you know you have 2+11 or 3+3 direct and second neighbours with bombs; an integer number of points means none, all, or exactly eight second neighbours have bombs.

Tricky. It will likely be harder to play for humans. For a computer player I assume it is easier.